# SwiftUI List row color inconsistent while scrolling in a NavigationView

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, navigationview

The background color of row views within a List inside a NavigationView inconsistently switch from transparent to white as I scroll.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

struct YourView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Your views")
        .listRowBackground(
            colorScheme == .light ? Color.white : Color(white: 0.09, opacity: 1)
        )
    }
}
```

`colorScheme` is necessary to support dark mode.